# Duda sobre pasar de una clase a otra c#

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase base llamada `Vehiculos` y aparte tengo otra clase llamada `Alquiler`. Resulta cuando realiza el alquiler tengo que mostrarle cual seria el precio total del alquiler, esto se hace multiplicando el costo diario del vehiculo(que se encuentra en la clase `Vehiculos`) por la cantidad de dias ( se encuentra en la clase `Alquiler`).
Para calcular haria dia2 - dia1 * costo diario

¿Como puedo hacer para pasar el costo diario para la clase alquiler?

```
   public double Costodiario
    {
        get { return costodiario; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 25)
                throw new Exception("El costo diario minimo es de 25 dolares");
            else
                costodiario = value;
        }
    }

  public int Dia1
    {
        get { return dia1; }
        set { dia1 = value; }
    }
    public int Mes1
    {
        get { return mes1; }
        set { mes1 = value; }
    }
    public int Anio1
    {
        get { return anio1; }
        set { anio1 = value; }
    }
    public int Dia2
    {
        get { return dia2; }
        set { dia2 = value; }
    }
    public int Mes2
    {
        get { return mes2; }
        set { mes2 = value; }
    }
    public int Anio2
    {
        get { return anio2; }
        set { anio2 = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Deberias mostrarnos el codigo. Pasar datos de una clase a otra es tan facil como igualar variables.

Comment: ahi edite , costo diario esta en la clase vehiculos y lo otro en la clase alquiler

Comment: Cuando decis una clase base llamada vehiculos entiendo que estas usando herencia, no le veo mucha relacion a los objetos. Pero deberias mostrar los campos que contienen las clases

Comment: exacto dentro de la clase vehiculos estan los autos y los utilitarios

Comment: Tu pregunta no esta bien explicada. Si queres saber el costo total solo deberías multiplicar el costo del auto diario, por la cantidad de días. No pones porque haces dia2 - dia1 ni tampoco para que tenes mes1 mes2 anio1, anio2

Comment: claro porque tengo fecha de inicio de alquiler y fecha fin

Comment: entiendo que pueden restarse los meses o incluso anos, pero eso lo quiero pasar a date time

Comment: Por dios las fechas hay q guardarlas en fechas..

Answer (score 2):

En el siguiente codigo calculo el costo de alquilar un vehiculo segun su coste diario y un rango en dias.
No he tenido en cuenta el tema de los horarios de alquiler pero este seria el caso básico:

```
using System;

namespace RentaCar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vehiculo auto = new Vehiculo();
            auto.CostoDiario = 100;
            Alquiler alq = new Alquiler(auto, new DateTime(2017, 7, 1), new DateTime(2017, 7, 3));
            Console.WriteLine("Costo:" + alq.CalcularCosto().ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Vehiculo
    {
        public double CostoDiario { get; set; }
    }

    public class Alquiler
    {
        Vehiculo _vehiculo;
        double _dias;

        public Alquiler(Vehiculo pVehiculo, DateTime desde, DateTime hasta)
        {
            this._vehiculo = pVehiculo;
            TimeSpan dif = hasta - desde;
            _dias = dif.TotalDays;
        }

        public double CalcularCosto()
        {
            double total = 0;
            total = _dias * _vehiculo.CostoDiario;
            return total;
        }
    }
}
```